# Grouping different amounts together in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

If I have a set of objects each with the same description, but with different amounts.

```
{

    {
    "_id": "101",
    "description": "DD from my employer1",
    "amount": 1000.33
    },
    {
    "_id": "102",
    "description": "DD from my employer1",
    "amount": 1000.34
    },
    {
    "_id": "103",
    "description": "DD from my employer1",
    "amount": 1000.35
    },
    {
    "_id": "104",
    "description": "DD from employer1",
    "amount": 5000.00
    },
    {
    "_id": "105",
    "description": "DD from my employer2",
    "amount": 2000.33
    },
    {
    "_id": "106",
    "description": "DD from my employer2",
    "amount": 2000.33
    },
    {
    "_id": "107",
    "description": "DD from my employer2",
    "amount": 2000.33
    }

}
```

Below, I am able to group them using the description:

```
{

    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "description": "$description"
            },
            "count": {
                "$sum": 1
            },
            "_id": {
                "$addToSet": "$_id"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "count": {
                "$gte": 3
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Is there a way to include all the amounts in the group **(_ids: 101, 102, and 103 plus 105,106,107)** even if they have a small difference, but exclude the bonus amount, which in the sample above is _id 104?

I don't believe it could be done in a group stage, but is there something that could be done at a later stage that could group _ids 101, 102 and 103 together and exclude _id 104.  Basically, I want MongoDB to ignore the small differences in 101, 102, 103 and group them together since the are paychecks coming from the same employer.

I have been working with **$stdDevPop**, but can't get a solid formula down.

I am looking for a simple array output of just the _ids.

{
  "result": [
      "101",
      "102",
      "103",
      "105",
      "106",
      "107" 
  ]
}

Comment: You can group by doing some math on the "amount", i.e round out to 1000's and `$push` the matching `_id` values to an array. **However**, presently your "amount" values are "strings". So you either fix that data by converting to a numeric value or live with the JavaScript evaluation of `mapReduce`. The aggregation framework operators cannot cast a string to numeric. But JavaScript can. Still, you "should" really fix your data.

Comment: Values are numeric.  Mistakenly shown as strings.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks.  I used the $trunc and then grouped by description and that truncated value and it is doing what I want it to do.

Comment: Actually was just finishing writing up an answer as you typed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by doing some math on the "amount" to round it down to the nearest 1000 and use that as the grouping `_id`:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "$subtract": [
           { "$trunc": "$amount" },
           { "$mod": [
             { "$trunc": "$amount" }, 
             1000
           ]}
         ]
      },
      "results": { "$push": "$_id" }
  }},
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": { "$gt": [ { "$size": "$results" }, 1 ] },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$results" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "results": { "$push": "$results" }
  }}
])
```

If your MongoDB is older than 3.2 then you would just need to use a long form with [`$mod`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mod/) of what [`$trunc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/trunc/) is doing. And if your MongoDB is older than 2.6 then rather than [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) you would [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/). So in the longer form this is:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "$subtract": [
           { "$subtract": [
             "$amount",
             { "$mod": [ "$amount", 1 ] }
           ]},
           { "$mod": [
             { "$subtract": [
               "$amount",
               { "$mod": [ "$amount", 1 ] }
             ]},
             1000
           ]}
         ]
      },
      "results": { "$push": "$_id" },
      "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$match": { "count": { "$gt": 1 } } },
  { "$unwind": "$results" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "results": { "$push": "$results" }
  }}
])
```

Either way the output is just the `_id` values whose amounts grouped to the boundaries with a count more than once.

```js
{ "_id" : null, "results" : [ "105", "106", "107", "101", "102", "103" ] }
```

You could either add a [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) in there or live with sorting the result array in client code.

Comment: @NeilLune, thanks, I'm working with 3.4 so the top looks like it works well.  The only modification that I did was add a $project of the results before the $unwind, because the $unwind was not running.

Comment: @Pablo.K You must have done something differently since the line in `$group` here `"results": { "$push": "$_id" }` creates an array. The only other statement in between is `$redact`, which does not modify the documents in any way, but just removes any documents that do not match the condition. Same goes for `$match` in the "all versions" compatible listing.

Comment: @Pablo.K If you have a new question then [Ask a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You should not alter your question here once answers have been given. StackOverflow is not a threaded discussion forum, but a place for submission of distinct questions and answers. So instead of altering the existing question and leaving comments. [Ask the Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead

Answer (score 0):

```
db.yourDBNameHere.aggregate( [
  { $match: { "amount" : { $lt : 5000 } } },
  { $project: { _id: 1 } },
])
```

that will grab the ID only of every transaction less than 5000$.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way, however, to make it more dynamic so not to hardcode the amount of 5000?

Comment: @Pablo.K what do you want the condition to be? MongoDB has plenty of mathematical operators, so what condition do you want it to exclude amounts on?

Comment: trying to exclude the outlier amount which above is the 5000. that is my main objective

Comment: That match statement already does that, it will only match entries where amount is less than 5000. You can set up a query with a variable if you want to be able to change what that amount is